# Using SSE to find the optimal model does not yield the correct solution

Tags: cross-validation, arima, model-selection

I am generating an AR(3) model with coefficients
$(\phi_1, \phi_2, \phi_3) = (0.35, 0.5, 0.08)$. Then I use the **statsmodels** module
from Python and its Yule-Walker implementation to get back the coefficients.

I find two problems:

- The estimation is not as accurate as I want
- When using the Sum of Square Errors formula (SSE) I find that
  p=4 instead of p=3 yields the least error. It should be p=3.

I will add my Python code here for reference:

```
# load libraries
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_pacf
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_process import ArmaProcess
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import pacf
from statsmodels.regression.linear_model import yule_walker
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# generate data using ArmaProcess
# some syntax taken from the Python statsmodels manual

N=1000 # number of samples

# random seed
np.random.seed(1)
# the phi_i coefficients
# arparms = np.array([0.35, 0.5, 0.08])
phi_1=0.35
phi_2=0.5
phi_3=0.08
arparms = np.array([phi_1, phi_2, phi_3])

# the beta_i coefficients
maparms = np.array([0]) # no moving average considered
ar = np.r_[1, -arparms] # add zero-lag and negate>
ma = np.r_[1, -maparms] # add zero lag  and negate
arma_process = ArmaProcess(ar, ma)
arma_process.isstationary
arma_process.isinvertible
arma_process.arroots
y=arma_process.generate_sample(N, scale=1)
def SSE(data, k, seed, N):
    # data :to be tested
    # k possible values for p
    # seed: to be able to reproduce the data as created initially
    # N: number of samples

    # define a loop of possibilities
    # initialize sse vector
    ssevec=np.zeros(k+1)

    for i in range(1,k+1):

        # random seed
        np.random.seed(seed)
        # get the coefficients
        phi, sigma = yule_walker(data, i, method='mle')  # we care only on phi
        print(phi)

        # create the new data with this phi
        arparms = phi
        # the beta_i coefficients
        maparms = np.array([0]) # no moving average considered
        ar = np.r_[1, -arparms] # add zero-lag and negate>
        ma = np.r_[1, -maparms] # add zero lag  and negate
        arma_process = ArmaProcess(ar, ma)
        y=arma_process.generate_sample(N, scale=1)

        # find the SEE
        sse = np.sum((y - data)**2)


        ssevec[i]=sse

    return ssevec[1:]  # ignore the zero in the first place

k=6
N=1000
seed=1
myssevec= SSE(y, k, seed, N)
myssevec

# find the ideal order p based on the SSE test
min_value = min(myssevec)  # skip the zero at the beginning


min_index = list(myssevec).index(min_value)  # need to cast array into a list
print(f' the ideal p is {min_index+1} with an SSE equal to {min_value}')
```

The result is:

the ideal p is 4 with an SSE equal to 201.87291336514215

It should be p=3

In addition, I believe this is not a programming issue.

Here is a code in R with the same parameters:

```
set.seed(1)
data=arima.sim(list(order=c(3,0,0), ar=c(0.35,0.5,0.08)), n=1000)

SSE=NULL
for (p in 1:5){
    m = arima(data, order=c(p,0,0), include.mean=FALSE)
    
    SSE[p] = sum(resid(m)^2)
    print(paste(SSE[p]))
    
}
```

The results for the SSEs are:

[1] "1516.22197415653"
[1] "1111.96217374379"
[1] "1095.65751612625"
[1] "1095.65425178515"
[1] "1092.39037726777"

which indicate that p=5 is optimal for this (p=3) problem.

I believe there is something fundamentally wrong in my thinking.

I found, interestingly, that for the coefficients:

```
phi_1=0.9
phi_2=-0.6
phi_3=0.3
```

The results are quite good. It seems that small coefficients create
uncertainty in the SSE computation.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is about using statsmodels. Programming questions are off-topic on Cross Validated and are better suited to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Regarding p=3 vs. p=4, are you obtaining in-sample SSE? Because that will drop by adding lags regardless of what the data generating process is. Regarding *The estimation is not as accurate as I want*, what do you mean by that?

Comment: @dipetkov :  I believe this is not a programming issue. Please review the update on the question  (and tahnks for point this out).  I included a code in R and the problem there seems to be worse, it find p=5 (where it should be p=3, and Python predicts p=4). I believe there is something fundamentally wrong in my thinking. Thanks again.

Comment: @RichardHardy : What do  you mean in-sample SSE?  I am computing SSE assuming models of p=1,2,3,4,5,6 coefficients and find which number p of coefficients yield the least SSE. It is my understanding that that p would be the ideal for the model. Is this right? Thanks.  (accurate is that if I say $\phi_1=0.35$ and I get $0.3229127$ I am off by about 3/10 from my exact assumption. To me that is a 30% error which is large.

Comment: Herman: You should look at the values of the coefficients of $m$ when each estimated model from arima in the loop is returned. That may give some insights as to what is going on as far as why the $p = 3$ case doesn't give the lowest SSE. Note though that, estimation of ARIMA models is very tricky in that the algorithm doesn't just minimize SSE. So, I'm not certain that one should expect the lowest SSE model to even be "the best".

Comment: @HermanJaramillo, in-sample SSE is the SSE of the model fitted on the same data on which it was trained (i.e. on which the parameters were estimated). It can be contrasted to out-of-sample SSE where the model is fit on one subset of data and then evaluated on another subset, and the SSE comes from the latter. A larger model (such as AR(4)) will always yield a lower in-sample SSE than a smaller model (such as AR(3)) by construction. This is regardless of what the actual data generating process is.

Comment: @HermanJaramillo, regarding what mlofton said about estimation, he is right in priciple, but I think this is a negligible issue in practice. You could check that by fitting the same model using `lm`; I bet the results would be very close.

Comment: @Rchard Hardy : Thanks for the explanation. Yes, I used the in-sample test. I generated the data with some parameters and the same data were tested to get these parameters back.